# Handling XML Schema (with namespaces) when some clients use namespaces and some don't

Tags: java, xml, spring, xjc

I'll apologize upfront for this being a rather unstructured question.  It's for an actual problem, but I'm writing this as more of a theoretical exercise.

Using Spring, I have a set of objects created via XJC from an XML Schema.  When a client properly uses namespaces, everything works fine.  When they don't... well, it doesn't.

I realize that the client is in the wrong, but as you know, the client is *never* in the wrong.

So, I'm trying to find a way to be able to marshall/unmarshall both versions of input.  I've tried a variety of JAXB and Jackson, but can't seem to work out how to do it, if it can be done at all.

Ideally, I'd have a single set of objects, using the appropriate marshalling objects based on the client.  For a given client, I know whether I'm receiving namespaces or not.

Additionally, the schema is unambiguous, so no two elements use the same name.

I've also considered just maintaining two object sets, but can't seem to get XJC to build objects leaving out the namespace qualifiers (and I'm not sure it really should, anyhow).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a "chameleon schema".

If a schema document is in no namespace, then it can be included (using xs:include) into a schema document that has a target namespace, and it will morph into that namespace.

This way schema document A defines a no-namespace schema, and schema document B (which xs:include's A) defines a schema for a namespace, sharing definitions with the same local name.

I've always thought it a highly ugly mechanism, but it seems to fit your requirements.

Comment: Interesting idea and one that I hadn't considered.  I'll do some research into it.  I'm not sure how it translates to lower level objects that allow the correct marshalling/unmarshalling.